# What is the difference between version.myappid.appspot.com and version.latest.myappid.appspot.com?

Tags: google-app-engine

The Google App Engine documentation says that the URL to access a specific version of an app deployed is  .latest..appspot.com. The GAE admin webpage however links to ..appspot.com in the Versions tab and omits the 'latest'.

Any idea what that 'latest' is for? Is it actually not needed? Is omitting it not taking you the latest code deployed for that specific version?

References:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*.latest.app.appspot.com` convention was originally the only way to access a specific version of your app. This was changed to simply accessing them directly as subdomains a while ago; `latest` was kept as a special case so as not to break old URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you have a link to something documenting this for completeness?

Comment: @ArielVardi I could swear we mentioned the change in release notes, but I can't find it. You can find links to the various versions in your admin console, which use the new notation.